# Como transformar um vetor aleatório em um vetor ordenado sem perder a correlação no Matlab

Tags: array, matlab

Olá, estou tentando rodar um programa de fluxo de potência (engenharia elétrica).
A rotina funciona perfeitamente se o vetor de número de barras é do tipo:

```
A=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]
```

O problema é que eventuamente me deparo com vetores do tipo:

```
B=[1;2;7;8;9;15;16;17]
```

Uma solução que estava pensando era correlacionar o vetor 'B' (que ocorre) com o vetor 'A' (criado durante a rotina).
O problema é que: uma vez que o programa rodar e convergir, eu preciso ter os resultados em função do vetor 'A' e não do vetor auxiliar 'B', portanto essa correlação não pode ser perdida.

A minha melhor ideia é criar uma matriz onde a coluna 1 é o vetor A e a coluna 2 é o vetor B. Existe alguma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: O que você chama de "vetor aleatório"? Para mim `B` está na mesma ordenação que `A`: não decrescente

Comment: Eu preciso necessariamente que o vetor comece em 1 e termine em N (onde N é o número ultima barra). Por isso a criação de um vetor auxiliar.

Comment: Você precisa de um vetor de números consecutivos começado em 1?

Comment: Exatamente! E não posso perder a correlação com o vetor A (desordenado) no caso.

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode ser uma falha na funcão que está usando o vetor `A`. Uma opcão melhor é averiguar a origem do problema, mas a solucão que é possível baseado na sua pergunta está abaixo.

Crie um vetor com todos os membros possíveis e depois selecione a sua resposta com o vetor original.

Nota:Veja bem que o vetor que você colocou é ordenado e não apresenta valores repetidos. Caso você tenha valores assim,  é necessário uma pequena adaptacão do código, para chamar na ordem e com valores repetidos( `ismember` ignora valores repetidos).

```
%vetor original
a=[3;7;10];
%vetor linearmente espacado
b=1:1:(max(a)+1);
%ajeito para coluna
b=b'; %Aqui o vetor está pronto pra usar. Use como entrada a seus cálculos.

% Assumindo a resposta está dada no vetor  ""r"", que pela sua explicacão 
% tem o mesmo tamanho do ""b""

r_ajustado=r(ismember(b,a)); %este vetor tem o mesmo tamanho de ""a"", 
%com os respectivos membros de ""a"".
```